# Select SubQuery for Comma Separated Values from Single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

From a Select Query I am getting following values in single row , not in different rows:

```
Id        Statuses
---     -------------
1       Released,In Progress,Completed
```

Now I want to write a query so that I should get all the orders that are in Statuses:

```
Select * from Orders where Status in (Select Statusesfrom StatusTable)
```

Comment: What you get from `StatusTable` is a single string, not a list of values.

Comment: upload some sample data from two tables.So the question is more clear.

Comment: Use dynamic sql or write a function to split those values and return in Single Column output

Comment: Any chance you could fix the problem instead of dealing with bad data? The problem is because you are violating 1NF by storing multiple values in a single column. Now you are struggling to get the data you want because of it. If at all possible fix the data and your queries will be simple.

Answer (score 1):

Adopt one of these splitters. You can write your own but you will see a lot has gone into researching these:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

This splits your value into a table with a single column. You can join on this after you run the function on it like:

```
Select o.* from Orders o
inner join splitTable s on o.keyColumn = s.Column
```

Answer (score 1):

After much discussion (as seen below), and testing, I modified my Parsing Function.   The new function will parse 250,000 strings generating 1,889,108 rows in 400ms.

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,Statuses varchar(250))
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1,'Released,In Progress,Completed'),
(2,'Released,In Progress')

Select A.ID
      ,B.* 
from @YourTable A
Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](A.Statuses,',')) B
Order By ID,Key_PS
```

Returns

```
ID  Key_PS  Key_Value   Key_Pos
1   1       Released    1
1   2       In Progress 10
1   3       Completed   22
2   1       Released    1
2   2       In Progress 10
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter varchar(50))
Returns Table 
As

--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('The quick brown fox',' ')

Return (
   with cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
        cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d) A ),
        cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
        cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

   Select Key_PS    = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
         ,Key_Value = Substring(@String, A.N, A.L) 
         ,Key_Pos   = A.N
   From   cte4 A
)
```

Just a couple of tweaks from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: This is a multi statement table valued function. They have been routinely known to be even worse than scalar functions on even moderate datasets. There are many inline table valued functions better than this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @SeanLange Yes you are correct, but the performance is still respectable.  30,000 records  145ms.

Comment: I know it is one your wrote and it is quite good but a proper inline function is right at your fingertips...why keep posting one that is not as fast?

Comment: @SeanLange 10 runs each (same 30K as mentioned above).  Your XML version is an average of 24ms faster.  The only thing is often require the row number.   So from now on, I will be using one or the other depending on my needs.   Thanks for the link and the nudge.

Comment: Certainly not my XML version but glad you did some testing. The time you really start to notice the difference is when you have a million rows or you have a larger number of elements per row. When either, or both, of those start happening the performance differences really start to show themselves. On small datasets with only a few elements per row the difference is negligible.

Comment: @SeanLange Boy! you're not kidding  250,000 Strings Generated 1,889,108 Rows in 4.2 seconds vs mine at 16.9 seconds.

Comment: For sheer performance you might check out this one too. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ Aaron mentioned it in the article I linked but his version was modified and the performance suffered horribly. This version is limited to 8k input length but you get row numbers back and it will out perform everything but CLR in almost every situation. This one does not get a lot of favor among the SO faithful but I use it more often than not.

Comment: @SeanLange OK, that is generating the same results in 450ms!!!  AND,  I have my ItemNumber.  I can see why it doesn't get much attention, it is pretty ugly, but hey, who am I to judge.

Comment: I don't think it is that ugly. Howerver, Aaron Bertrand is a super heavy hitter around here and in his opinion it isn't a valid splitter because it has a limitation of 8k characters inbound. Nearly everything I ever have to split is WAY less then that, more like 100-400 character range. Plus I have a cteTally on my system already so I left that out of the delimited split function that I use. Once you understand that code it really isn't too bad or ugly at all. And wow is it fast!!!! :)

Comment: @SeanLange Taking it step-by-step so I don't destroy performance.  Have my own tally table as well.   FYI, I tried varchar(max) and it killed the performance.

Comment: If you haven't yet looked through the comments on the SSC article you should. There have been some improvements over time that never made it back to the article just yet. I think you may find that community welcoming based on what I have seen of you here on SO.

Comment: @SeanLange Back at my desk and I updated my answer and UDF based on your suggestions.  Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

Use STRING_SPLIT() function , if you are using SQL Server 2016.

```
     SELECT *
     FROM Orders 
      WHERE Status IN (SELECT Value FROM  StatusTable
                         CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Statuses,','))
```